# Is "get benefits" correct in this context?

Tags: nouns, indirect-objects

I am writing this context:

> Culture exchange is very important for societies in order to **get benefits** from each other. One form of culture exchange is creating good connections between academic institutions.

Is "get benefits" correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get benefits` is correct but `cultural exchange` is more commonly used than `culture exchange`.